# Am I allowed to edit an old question I posted that has been closed?

Tags: discussion

As stated, I asked a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158482/looking-for-the-title-of-a-tad-williams-style-book) over 5 years ago that was closed due to "Needs to be more focused". Now, the irony is that I was recently in a Half Priced Bookstore, and found the book I was asking about. As I was purchasing it, I was telling the person that I'd asked on here YEARS ago about it. Now that I've found it, I was wondering the rules on posting an update. For reference, here's the book:

[image]

Comment: I think it's best not to edit in information which you learned _after_ having found the work. My vote would be to reopen just to add a self-answer, in case it _might_ help anyone else remembering the same details.

Comment: Aw man... that was the first book that came to mind when I saw your question, but it is reopened so that you can answer (and you can self-accept immediately). Don't forget to make the answer as detailed as it would be if you were trying to convince someone else that you'd found their answer.

Answer (score 18):

You should post a comment on the question that you've discovered the answer, and flag the question to be reopened.  Once the question is reopened, you can answer it and accept your answer.

Note that "needs focus" and "needs clarity" are frequently judgment calls anyway, and the community in general is open to revisiting these statuses if the circumstances change.